# solving for x in $x^x-x^{-x}=(1+x)^{-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve $x^x-x^{-x}=(1+x)^{-x}$.
I tried to express $x^x-x^{-x}$ as $2 \sinh(x \ln x)$ but it didn't seem to make things easier. Any ideas?

Comment: For $x>0$, $x^x = e^{x\ln x}$.

Comment: $x=-1$ is an obvious solution.

Comment: @AlexSilva  Well, watch out for the RHS ...

Comment: $x^x$ should be generally regarded as define on $(0,\infty)$. Let $f(x)=x^x, g(x)=x^{-x}+(1+x)^{-x}$. Function graphs shows that there is one and only one intersection in $(1,2)$.  Highly doubt there will be an analytical solution.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, the RHS gives $(1-1)^{1}=0$. Am I wrong? I think $x^x$ is well defined for $x < 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It seems that $x^x=0.2+\sqrt{1.04}$ will do the job.

Comment: @AlexSilva Ups, my fault.